# rbind whatever is present in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, sometimes.

Sometimes `df1` is present, sometimes it isnt. The same goes for `df2`.

I want to `rbind` `df1` and `df2` together but I dont want to write a load of messy nested if conditions to see if they exist. I just want to call rbind and for it to bind together whatever it finds.

I've tried:

```
  if(!is.null(df2)){
      if(exists("df1") && !is.null(df1)){
        Finalmerge<-rbind(df2,df1)
      }
    }
    else if(is.null(df2)){Finalmerge<-df1}
    else if(!exists(df1)|is.null(df1)){Finalmerge<-df2}
```

but it makes my head spin and doesn't really work anyway. Is there a way of saying- just rbind whatever is there and dont worry about it if something isnt there?

Comment: Is `df1` object is not present at all in the environment or it is `NULL` ?

Comment: Hi Can be both.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem, could you explain, how do you end up with  "I have two dataframes, sometimes" ?

Comment: Each dataframe is generated by a conditional statement

Comment: If those statements could output the dfs into a list, then we could just use `rbindlist`.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your data frames dynamically, simply store your data frames in a list so that you can run

```
do.call(rbind, some_list_of_dataframes)
```

This can really help you if you have multiple data frames generated dynamically and you store them in a list rather than separate data frames.

However, if you want to get all existing objects that are named similarly, you can use e.g. [`ls()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ls.html):

```
ls(pattern = "^df")
#> [1] "df1" "df2"
```

It lists all objects with name starting at "df" that exist in your environment.

To get their vaules, simply use [`get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) (for one object) or [`mget()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) (for making a list of all of them).

See this:

```r
# example data
df1 <- mtcars[1:2, ]
df2 <- mtcars[3:4, ]

# get all df...
dataframes <- ls(pattern = "^df")

# rbind them
all <- do.call(rbind, mget(dataframes))

print(all)
#>                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> df1.Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> df1.Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> df2.Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> df2.Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this:

```
library(purrr)

ls(pattern = "^df") %>%
reduce(~ possibly(rbind, otherwise = NULL)(get(.x)))
```

Comment: And if the data frames are names differently?

Comment: Then you just need to provide the adequate pattern

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, I like to suggest using `data.table` for rbinding and `Filter`:

```
candidates <- ls()
candidates <- lapply(candidates, get)
candidates <- Filter(is.data.frame, candidates)
result <- data.table::rbindlist(candidates)
```

Using `data.table::rbindlist` is said to be more efficient than `do.call(rbind, candidates)`. You can convert the resulting `data.table` back to a `data.frame`.